# R: Using user input to pass functions and parameters as parameters to higher-order functions

Tags: r, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am not sure if this is doable (at least the way I am trying to do this), but I really hope so.  I have a fairly complex testing environment that I am developing in R, and it would really help if I could pass functions and their associated parameters as arguments to higher-order functions.  I can do this without asking for user input easily enough, but that fact that readline() results in character strings makes what I am trying to do a bit tricky.  Here is a simplified version (note that I am assuming a numeric value for the parameter input, but in reality, I am error-checking data type in my real code.  This is just simplification to get the point across):

```
read_in <- function(){
    temp_nm <- readline(prompt = paste("Enter the name of parameter: "))
    temp_vlu <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = paste("Enter the value for ",temp_nm,": ")))
    assign(temp_nm,temp_vlu,envir = .GlobalEnv)
    temp_param <- as.name(temp_nm)
    temp_params <- list(temp_param)
    return(temp_params)
}
```

I know that this does not quite work, as it returns the following:

```
> read_in()
Enter the name of parameter: this_param
Enter the value for  this_param : 12
[[1]]
this_param
```

This is close, as it does assign the value of 12 to this_param in the global environment, but I am really looking to return

```
> read_in()
Enter the name of parameter: this_param
Enter the value for  this_param : 12    
[[1]]
this_param = 12
```

so I can pass this_param = 12 as a parameter to another higher-order function (in addition to the actual function to which this_param is an argument).  Again, this is highly simplistic compared with what I am actually trying to do, which is pass a series of functions and associated parameters as arguments to higher-order functions, while using a UI rather than manually inputting a call to my higher-order function which will be quite long and prone to human error.  In general, figuring out how to achieve what I laid out above would help my development tremendously, so any input would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into the scope assignment operator `<<-` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `do.call` you can pass named lists to functions

```
read_in <- function() {
  temp_nm <- readline(prompt = paste("Enter the name of parameter: "))
  temp_vlu <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = paste("Enter the value for ",temp_nm,": ")))
  setNames(list(temp_vlu), temp_nm)
}

f <- function(x, y, some_param) {
  some_param
}

out <- read_in()
# Enter the name of parameter: some_param
# Enter the value for  some_param : 12
# some_param 
#         12 

do.call('f', out)
# [1] 12
```

Comment: Totally apologize, and I will do so now.  Thanks for the head's up!!